# SciKit Learn Train Classifier on Big Data

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am working with scikit-learn training decision tree classifiers.

Scikit-learn requires that, for training, all data be loaded and provided upfront as

```
clf.fit(features, ys)
```

However, my features and ys are loaded from data files which are several GBs and cannot load them all in Python at once.

Is there some way to address the issue?

I can't think of an obvious solution as Decision Trees rely on information gain/entropy decrease, which requires an overview of all data at once, but I thought somebody might have previously come across a similar problem.

Comment: An answer to this question exists [on the cross-validated exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305021/incremental-learning-with-decission-trees-scikit-learn/305033). The short answer is that there is indeed no obvious solution, since sklearn's decision trees do not implement `partial_fit`, but the problem can be circumvented with some effort.

Comment: As @Arne has already said - sklearn can't do it out of the box - here is a list of [incremental (that have `partial_fit()` method) estimators](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning). Maybe it's time to start thinking of using Apache Spark?